# Subir imágenes en Django haciendo insert en dos tablas con FK

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Tengo un proyecto **Django 1.9** en el cual tengo una vista del **Admin** preparada para subir fotos, pero claro, quiero enlazarlas a otra tabla, es decir algo así como una tabla **FOTOS** y otra **CASAS** y no es muy coherente ir subiendo todas las fotos y una vez subidas enlazarlas a la casa.

Quisiera hacer un vista en el cual se cargue la información de la casa (ya la tengo) y el otro apartado para subir fotos, y al ser nuevo en django y python no sé como debería estructurar el código para juntar ambos apartados en uno y que se haga el insert en ambas tablas de la base de datos.

Es decir que cuando un usuario quiera añadir una casa o editarla desde el mismo formulario pueda subir más fotos o borrar las existentes.

Comment: Has probado con TabularInline o StackedInline https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline? o hablas de una alternativa a este tipo de vistas?

Answer (score 1):

Yo empezaría recomendando un enfoque diferente. Es muy raro que se empiece el desarrollo de Django por las vistas, porque generalmente se inicia con el diseño de los modelos. La razón es muy simple, los modelos describen el negocio y su lógica; la vista solo describe una forma de presentarlos, por ejemplo, una parte de los datos.

> Me preocupa un poco que uses el término *"tabla"*. En Django, ese término casi nunca se ocupa, porque queda detrás del gestor de base de datos (se llama *Object Relationship Mapping*, pero es muy complicado de traducir). Claro que existe la posibilidad que la base ya exista, pero no hay indicios en tu post que este sea el caso.

Primero, deberías definir correctamente tus modelos. Lo más conveniente, siempre *desde mi punto de vista*, es que el modelo `Foto` esté relacionado con el modelo `Casa`.

```
from django.db import models


class Casa(models.Model):
    pass


class Foto(models.Model):
    casa = models.ForeignKey(Casa)
    foto = models.ImageField()
```

De este modo, se cada foto que subas **al modelo** `Foto` tendrá una relación al modelo `Casa` y en Django puedes acceder a las fotos **¡desde cada casa!**

```
casa = Casa.object.get(pk=1)
casa.foto_set.all()
```

Te recomiendo que sigas el tutorial de Django, la [segunda parte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/intro/tutorial02/) describe dos modelos de una forma que te puede ayudar a entender tu planteamiento.

- La documentación sobre el tipo de campo `ForeignKey`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related
- La referencia a `casa.foto_set.all()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward